# set background for navigation menu and when click on the background the navigation must be closed

Tags: javascript, html, css

i create the navigation [Demo](https://codepen.io/kianoush/pen/GRpwZJy?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=4cde831a0a0fed8e4867593f60599e95ad887872-1589790070-0-Ae_sXkRmmzuWcGGy8VHqc1PHZhsBamxLaKSNmOOyEQ9BvB3dFIJmBqADykjp580NP0Zk8926YJqTenvqNankwnIl5sbYjlJllUTDUAeyPfrkMXpx5HpcFovohPTr8IdvkhWCqRzBNJqglBSf7Ozn17bY5m_ZCKn8ZrlTAdTBStVRJjvToy2RSUo2iE0cyyXXJEWutbmokEfhvK-_f1SnS1QKCDcf-qheGBMvoSe9RhULRAFUGUuRsc3vx3snP8nDNcDqhh4-eICHtWm22enHWCFVVtYichdcUMOHsuUY6LT8vSlGlaq8q5wm1ZwxQg50RpOZsH4JdLn3W-Rngwzf807fzExLaT5J5H37jSF1RDZW) and i want to set a black background and that width must be `100%` and when click on the background the navigation must be closed .

the important things about this navigation is this the content must be 80% but the background must be 100% .

```
 <div id="activity-info" class="activity-info">
<div class="activity-container">
  <div class="activity-header">
    <span id="closeActivityInfo" (click)="closeActivityInfo()">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </span>
    <div class="activity-info-title">
      <span>
        {{ "GENERAL.ACTIVITY_INFO" | translate }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="activity-content">
    <div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-label">{{ "GENERAL.CREATOR" | translate }} :</div>
        <div class="item-value">
          <pfa-user-field
            [displayName]="oldEditModel.creator"
            [row]="false"
          ></pfa-user-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css Code :

```
   #showInfos {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: 7px !important;
  }
  #closeActivityInfo {
    display: block;
  }
  .activity-info-title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .activity-info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  .activity-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .edit-form {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .form-content {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .showInfos {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #e52727;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

js Code :

Comment: Why don't you set `#activity-info` at 100% width with black background and  `.activity-container` at 80% width with red background ?

Comment: I solved  and added codes. Check it. @mr coder

Comment: @CanUver i try your code but it not worked https://codepen.io/kianoush/pen/GRpwZJy

Comment: Because you mixed up the codes. be careful I don't give onclick events anywhere. I wrote javascript separately for events. What I've written is true, nothing short of it. Works now. https://codepen.io/codebyalican/pen/yLYQbyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I've edited your codes to make a more logical classification I've rearranged all your codes. I mentioned my changes in the comment lines. if I understand you correctly, you want to do these things.

Css:

```
.activity-info {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black; /* Add black background */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    margin-top: 29px;  /* padding to margin,  calc button height */
  }

  .activity-container { 
    width: 80%;  /* 100% to 80% */
    height: 100%; /* add 100%*/
    background-color: red; /*background color red added*/
  } 

  .activity-info.showNavbar { // if this class is in the activity-info, it specifies the changes that will happen.
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
  const navbarButton = document.getElementById("showInfos");
  const activityInfo = document.querySelector(".activity-info")

  navbarButton.addEventListener("click", e => { 
     activityInfo.classList.toggle("showNavbar")
  })

  activityInfo.addEventListener("click", e => {
     if (e.target.classList.contains("activity-info")) {
            activityInfo.classList.remove("showNavbar")
     }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you should update the function openNav() to set the width of the background 100% when opened, and the CSS to set the content width to 80%. If you want to close the navigation by clicking on the background you'll have to move the onclick event to that wrapper (from what I'm seeing right now you applied that function to the span with mat-icon clear) and write a function closeActivityInfo() similar to the openNav().

So, HTML:

```
<button mat-raised-button onclick="openNav()" id="showInfos" color="primary">
   Click for Open
</button>

<div id="activity-info" class="activity-info" onclick="closeActivityInfo()">
<div class="activity-container">
  <div class="activity-header">
    <span id="closeActivityInfo">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </span>
    ...
```

CSS (posting only the updated part):

```
.activity-container {
   width: 80%;
   background: red;
}
```

js:

```
function openNav(){
   document.getElementById("activity-info").style.width = "100%";
   document.getElementById("activity-info").style.left = 0;
   document.getElementById("activity-info").style.right = 'auto';
}
function closeActivityInfo() {
   document.getElementById("activity-info").style.width = "0";
}
```